# I want to set values for array in one process and access it in another process nodejs

Tags: arrays, node.js, global

```
 main.js
var sendTickets = []

code1.js
for(i=0;i<100;i++){
sendTickets.push(i);
}

code2.js
sendTickets.forEach(function(element){console.log(element);})
```

I am setting array variable-sendTickets in `main.js`. And I want to fill that array in `code1.js` and display it in `code2.js`. Is it possible in `nodejs`?

Comment: There are plently of IPC (Inter Process Communication) solutions, but you need to be more specific on what _exactly_ it is you're trying to achieve. Your example is too simple and because of that it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: not I dont want IPC without IPC I want to do it.

Comment: I mean IPC in general, not something specific. You need _some_ form of IPC because you're dealing with separate processes...

Comment: if I set global.sendTickets = [] is also not working

Comment: Because NodeJS can't share variables across processes.

Comment: how are those processes started? This could help.

Comment: i am starting that process in individual cmd prompts and starting node main.js , node code1.js, node code2.js

Comment: you will need some sort of IPC (inter-process comunication is what you are looking for...), or roll your own strange solution that will probably be less eficcient, like using a file and use fs.watch to check when is being modified... I suggest your try making a master and forking , or using redis...

Comment: How is it going? did you find any problems / inconvenience with my suggestions? If you want to briefly explain what code1 and code2 do, then maybe we can suggest a better alternative :)

Comment: actually i want to fetch  records in array from mango in code1.js at the same time code2.js needs to retrieve records from that array

Comment: have you tried forking code1 and code2 ? or using redis for sharing the array ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use global scope, since JS is single Thread runtime, you even will not face any race condition from it.

```
main.js:
global.sendTickets = []

code1.js
for(i=0;i<100;i++){
global.sendTickets.push(i);
}

code2.js
global.sendTickets.forEach(function(element){console.log(element);})
```

Comment: `global` is not shared across processes. They aren't just splitting the code over separate files, but also over processes.

Comment: then is there any other solutions

Comment: @hariprasad like I said: IPC. `process.send()`, Redis, ØMQ, RabbitMQ, Kafka, NSQ, take your pick.

Answer (score 0):

## Redis

> Redis is an open source (BSD licensed), in-memory data structure
>   store, used as a database, cache and message broker.

```
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient(); //creates a new client
```

By default, redis.createClient() will use 127.0.0.1 and 6379 as the hostname and port respectively.

[Article : Using Redis with Node.js](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-redis-node-js/)

You will be able to set/get the array with no problem from any process/machine

(It might be overkill compared to forking a child and using nodes default ipc for doing the same)

## child_process.fork

> If the Node.js process is spawned with an IPC channel (see the [Child
>   Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) and [Cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) documentation), the 'message' event is emitted
>   whenever a message sent by a parent process using childprocess.send()
>   is received by the child process.

So you can have a `main.js` and fork `code1.js & code2.js` as children.